# Run `source` from package.json to set Enviroment-Variables for an script-run

Tags: linux, macos, environment-variables, package.json, fastlane

I have some `script`-Entries in my package.json.

For deploying an App via Fastlane to an appstore, I need to set enviroment-Variables for APPLE_ID or for the JSON-File of google-services.

This settings are individual per User (and maybe per Project).

I know, how to add an hardcoded ENV-Variable via package.json:

```
"ANDROID_closedBeta": "FASTLANE_JSON_KEY_FILE=`find $(pwd) -name release_manager.json` bundle exec fastlane android deploy_closedBeta",
```

But thats doesn't solve my Problem. I have created an File: **ios_env** and **linux_env** which exports some sensitive credentials.

If I run `source linux_env`, the variables are set and I can run fastlane without any issue via CLI-Command: `fastlane  android deploy_closedBeta`

But if I try to run it via yarn or npm, this ENV will not found.
So I've tried to run source in front of the falstlane-command, but also didn't work:

```
"ANDROID_closedBeta": "`source ./linux_env` FASTLANE_JSON_KEY_FILE=`find $(pwd) -name release_manager.json` bundle exec fastlane android deploy_closedBeta",
```

How can I get the package.json-script to recognise my enviroment-Variables without the need to hardcode it into package.json?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an ugly workaround... but would be glad if somebody could show me a better way to to:

In package.json I declare two settings. One which has the main Script which need the still received ENV-Variables, and one Script-entry that loads first the Enviroment and then run the main-Script-Task within this enviroment.

Hard to explain, easy to show... look at this:

```
"scripts": {
...
   "IOS_internalTest": "source ./fastlane/ios_env && IOS_DEPLOY_TYPE=deploy_internalTest npm run IOS_runDeployment",
   "IOS_betaTest": "source ./fastlane/ios_env && IOS_DEPLOY_TYPE=deploy_betaTest npm run IOS_runDeployment",
   "IOS_runDeployment": "bundle exec fastlane ios $IOS_DEPLOY_TYPE",
...
}
```

First entry `source` my file, where all my ENV Exports are (like `export BIMBOM=FooBar`)
After finish, it executes `npm run IOS_doInternalTest`. Because it's run in the same shell-context, the ENV-Variables I've `source`ed before, are still available.

***Kudos to you, if you got an solution in an one-liner***